# Initializing a character inside a structure

Tags: c, structure

```
#define NAMESIZE 20

struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct rectangle {
    struct point upperleft;
    struct point lowerright;
    char label[NAMESIZE + 1];
};
```

In my main

```
int main(void) {


    struct rectangle r1;
    r1.upperleft.x = 1;
    r1.upperleft.y = 4;
    r1.lowerright.x = 4;
    r1.lowerright.y = 1;
    strcpy_s(r1.label, NAMESIZE, "hi");




    printf("Upper left: (%d, %d)\n", r1.upperleft.x, r1.upperleft.y);
    printf("Lower Right: (%d, %d)\n", r1.lowerright.x, r1.lowerright.y);
    printf("Name of rectangle: %d", r1.label);
    return 0;
}
```

My rectangle name is a memory address, how am i supposed to properly initialize the character variable of my structure?

Comment: Use `%s` instead of `%d` in `printf("Name of rectangle: %d", r1.label);`

Comment: @Marian is correct as well, but thats unrelated to the title question. Although, he forgot the `&` character too.

Answer (score 1):

```
    struct rectangle r1 = {{1,4}, {4,1}, "hi"};

    printf("Upper left: (%d, %d)\n", r1.upperleft.x, r1.upperleft.y);
    printf("Lower Right: (%d, %d)\n", r1.lowerright.x, r1.lowerright.y);
    printf("Name of rectangle: %s", r1.label);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will clear it: `memset(&r1.label, 0, sizeof(r1.label))`

This is the correction to what you have: `strcpy_s(&r1.label, NAMESIZE+1, "hi");`

`&` returns "the address of". So `&r1.label` is the address of the label in r1.

Comment: `strcpy_s(r1.label, NAMESIZE+1, "hi");` is sufficient - no `&`.

Comment: @chux strcpy_s takes a pointer as the first argument, therefore there is an implicit cast taking place. personally, i hate implicit casts because something might change in the future or you might be working with a non-standards compliant version of stdc.